# min n elements with expensive or deleted default constructor

Tags: c++, stl, default-constructor

Given an array `v` (some **STL** container, e.g. `std::vector< double >`) of generally unsorted data (say `assert(std::is_same< typeof(v), V >::value);`). Over the elements of the array is defined comparison operator, say `std::less`. You need to create an array with `n` minimal elements (copies form `v`), but the elements are **not default constructible** (or is expensive operation). How to do it by means of **STL**? Non-modifying sequence algorithm is required.

Originally seen as a way to solve using `std::back_insert_iterator`, but there is some confusion as explained further:

```
assert(!std::is_default_constructible< typename V::value_type >::value); // assume

template< class V >
V min_n_elements(typename V::const_iterator begin, typename V::const_iterator end, typename V::size_type const n)
{
    assert(!(std::distance(begin, end) < n));
    V result; // V result(n); not allowed
    result.reserve(n);
    std::partial_sort_copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(result), /*What should be here? mb something X(result.capacity())?*/, std::less< typename V::value_type >());
    return result;
}
```

I want to find solution that is optimal in terms of time and memory (O(1) additional memory and <= O(`std::partial_sort_copy`) time consumption). Totally algorithm should operate on the following number of memory: `v.size()` elements of non-modifiable source `v` as input and `n` of newly created elements, all of which are copies of the `n` smallest elements of source array `v`, as output. That's all. I think this is a realistic limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: reimplemented with heap:

```
template< class V > 
V min_n_elements(typename V::const_iterator b, typename V::const_iterator e, typename V::size_type const n) {
   assert(std::distance(b, e) >= n);
   V res(b, b+n);
   make_heap(res.begin(), res.end());

   for (auto i=b+n;  i<e;  ++i) {
        if (*i < res.front())  {
              pop_heap(res.begin(), res.end());
              res.back() = *i;
              push_heap(res.begin(), res.end());
        }
   }

   return std::move(res);
}
```

Comment: This solution is too expensive in terms of memory.

Comment: Fine, but then the question arises: do not allocated additional memory at the time of the make_heap function call?

Comment: I am not sure I've understood what you are asking, `make_heap` does not allocates additional memory.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to hear. Whether the correct estimate of the complexity of the problem is _O() ~ 3 * n + (N - n) * (2 * log n + log n) ~ (N - n) * log n_ comparisons (where N == `v.size()`, n == `res.size()`)?

Comment: If we account for `make_heap` complexity too, it should be `O(N * log n)`, same as for `partial_sort_copy`.  But it should be faster because it does not do sorting at the and.  Partial_sort_copy uses heap too.

Comment: Complexity of `make_heap` is at most, (3*(last-first)) comparisons [(link)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/).

Comment: Why you decline my correction with superfluous `std::move`? `std::move` on return value is superfluous. Because it prohibits to perform the NRVO to compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you also need those elements sorted, it's probably easiest and fastest to use `std::nth_element`, then `std::copy`.

```
template <class InIter, class OutIter>
min_n_elements(InIter b, InIter e, OutIter o, InIter::difference_type n) {
   InIter pos = b+n;
   std::nth_element(b, pos, e);
   std:copy(b, pos, o);
}
```

`std::nth_element` not only finds the given element, but guarantees that those elements less than that are two it's "left", and those greater are to its "right".

This does side-step the real problem a bit though -- instead of actually creating the container for the results, it simply expects the user to create a container of the correct type, and then provide an iterator (e.g., a back_insert_iterator) to put the data in the right place. At the same time, I think this is really the correct thing to do -- the algorithm to find N minimum elements and the choice of container for the destination are separate.

If you really want to put the result in a specific container type anyway, that shouldn't be terribly difficult though:

```
template <class V>
V n_min_element(V::iterator b, V::iterator e) { 
     V::const_iterator pos = b+n;
     nth_element(b, pos, e);
     V ret(b, pos);
     return V;
}
```

As they stand, these do modify the (order of elements in) the input, but given that you've said the input isn't sorted, I'm assuming their order doesn't matter, so that should be permissible. If you can't do that, the next possibility is *probably* to create a collection of pointers, and use a comparison function that compares based on the pointees, then do your nth_element on that, and finally copy the pointees to the new collection.

Comment: This implementation requires more time to execute than the specified for the algorithm `std::partial_sort_copy` (your solution has a O(N^2) > O(`std::partial_sort_copy`) == O(N * log(N_2) according to the standard). This is redundant. I'm sure there are more interesting and effective solutions.

Comment: @Dukales: the standard does sort of allow nth_element to be O(N*N) worst case, but average complexity is linear. If you want to guarantee linear complexity, you can implement your own version of nth_element using the median of medians algorithm (and live with the fact that it's normally going to be slower than one based on Hoare's select algorithm).

Comment: @jogojapan: Oops -- corrected. Thanks for reminding me of the correct arguments.